# Block not completed before segue

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch, segue

A block is not complete prior to the next view controller being pushed. Any suggestions on how to delay or restructure the following:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ResultsView"])
{
    [self.spinner startAnimating];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        results = [self generateResults];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self.spinner stopAnimating];

            ResultViewController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
            controller.results = results;

        });
    });
}
}
```

This is the generateResults method:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)generateResults
{
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
__block NSMutableArray *matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                       usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{
    if (group) {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){

            if (asset)
            {
                //work done here.
            }
        }];
    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
}];

return matches;
}
```

Alternatively, when I don't use dispatch syncing, then same issue, the block to generate results is completed too late. The next view controller already appears showing 0 finds.

Comment: Change into your storyboard(not use the push view of storyboard provide) and replace function - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender. by another function but do the same things.then the block will do work.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `prepareForSegue` merely serves as preparation. That is, **once it's done, the segue will execute**. Therefore, if you need to prepare the controller before the segue occurs, you cannot put this task in an async block.  **As far as the runloop is concerned, your `prepareForSegue` completes immediately**.

If your next controller is dependent on preparatory code within `prepareForSegue`, then you should not do a `dispatch_async`.  Instead, either let `generateResults` execute on the main queue, or let `ResultViewController` dispatch the task async, and update its own view based on the result.

Comment: the next view controller requires it. If I execute it in the main queue then the block finishes after the next view controller has init. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, here is what I've done. There was no need to use dispatch. Alternatively, the block is complete when `group == nil`. So a simple `else` statement would do just fine.

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ResultView"])
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    __block NSMutableArray *matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                           usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
     {
         if (group) {
             [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
             [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){

                 if (asset)
                 {

                 }
             }];
         } else {

             ResultsViewController *resultsViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
             resultsViewController.results = matches;
             [resultsViewController.collectionView reloadData];
         }
     } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
     }];
}
```

}